# d3.tip is not a function: webpack and typescript

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I'm using d3 with Typescript and webpack.

In `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.38",
    "@types/d3-tip": "^3.5.5",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "d3-tip": "^0.7.1",
    ...
  },
```

In my code, d3 works fine, but `d3.tip()` does not. It all compiles fine, however when I run the code in my browser, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: d3.tip is not a function
```

If I evaluate `d3.tip` in the console, I get `undefined`. If I try and use:

```
import * as d3 from "d3"
import * as d3Tip from "d3-tip";

d3.tip = d3tip
```

I get:

```
Cannot assign to 'tip' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
```

What is going on? How do I use d3.tip correctly?

Comment: With current version of d3-tip, there is a bug.

Comment: Have you tried to make it work? If yes, how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this as follows:

```
import * as d3 from "d3"
import * as d3Tip from "d3-tip"
(d3 as any).tip = d3Tip
```

The `(d3 as any)` prevents the compiler complaining that d3.tip is a readonly property.

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives the following error

ERROR TypeError: d3__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.tip is not a function