# D3-tip and NPM: "TypeError: m.tip is not a function"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, npm, tooltip

I'm writing a React wrapper around D3 and am getting an error while trying to use D3-tip: `TypeError: m.tip is not a function`.

I've seen similar posts about this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569419/d3-tip-is-not-a-function-webpack-and-typescript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090730/using-d3-tip-with-npm-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-node-of-undef)), as well as [this issue](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/issues/145) on the d3-tip GitHub but neither worked in my case. I have used NPM to install D3 4.12.2 and D3-tip 0.7.1, so the version issues mentioned in those links should not apply.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3Tip from 'd3-tip';

svg = d3.select('#' + divId)
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('height', height);

g_node = svg.append('g')
                    .attr('id', 'g_node');

var node_circles = g_node.selectAll('circle')
                                .data(dataset, function(d) { return d.name; });

var tool_tip = d3Tip.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-8, 0]);

svg.call(tool_tip);

node_circles.enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('cx', function(d) { return projection(d.pos)[0]; })
                .attr('cy', function(d) { return projection(d.pos)[1]; })
                .attr('r', '' + NODE_RADIUS + 'px')
                .attr('fill', 'blue')
                .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                    tool_tip.show(d);
                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                    tool_tip.hide(d);
                });
```

Any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? For instance, `console.log(d3Tip)`, to see what d3Tip is?

Answer (score 1):

I would tweak a few things in order to get this working.

For example,

The alias importing can be as simple as
`import d3Tip from 'd3-tip'`

d3Tip is the alias for the default function returned from the index file in the d3-tip repo.

Following this, call d3Tip in order to get a `tip` object back, e.g. call `d3Tip()` to get the `var tooltip` you were using.

Now, you have a tip object and don't need to call `.tip()` anymore :)

Comment: import d3Tip from 'd3-tip' results in ts] Module '"/home/tomasz/work/ANGULAR/D3/D3_DEMO/node_modules/@types/d3-tip/index"' has no default export.

Comment: Sounds like an import issue; try using {} around your import class just in case it’s not a default export. If it doesn’t work look at the exports in the source code.

Comment: I used this and it worked. I use requires though. `d3tip = require('d3-tip')` and then use d3tip for whatever I need.